# Is it possible to monitor Jboss or apache server using Prometheus?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I'm working on monitoring and I used Prometheus with alertManager to alert user if filesystem is full, I'm looking if it is possible to monitor Jboss and Apache servers using Prometheus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Jboss you can use the [jmx_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter).

Apache doesn't produce good metrics, so you can use [mtail](https://github.com/google/mtail) or the [grok_exporter](https://github.com/fstab/grok_exporter) on the logs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does each exporter have its own system requirements (Linux or Unix) ?

Comment: Everything should run pretty much everywhere.The node exporter is only useful on Unix